# nodeSSPI authentication issue from REST Client POSTMan

Tags: node.js, authentication, node-modules

I am using nodeSSPI module to authenticate my node js application and it works fine as long as the request is from the browser but when I try to request i.e. GET,POST etc. from POST Man Client it always returns 401 Unauthorized

I dont fully understand the mechanics of nodeSSPI library but I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction

The code is pretty straight forward to be honest.

```
var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({authoritative: true, domain: 'XYZ'});
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err) {if (!res.finished) {next()}})
})
```

Here is the link to the node-sspi package as I am not allowed to create a new tag on SO yet, I am posting the link to the module.
[Node SSPI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi)

Answer (score 0):

Nick,

Use [ARC](https://install.advancedrestclient.com), and create a new request as needed. Add a new **Authorization** header to the request, click the pencil icon on the right, and add your *Windows* credentials.

ARC will automatically *Base64Encode* your credentials, and amend *Basic* to the header. This worked for me as I had the same issue / set-up as you.

[image]